# How to Check Which Version of Powershell Was Used to Write a Script

Tags: powershell

Is this possible?

I ask because I have a script which works on my PC but not on the client machine, and it will be a waste of time trying to debug if it wont work simply because the script uses the wrong version.

Thanks

---

The script I am trying to run (from the top of a logon script):

```
try {
    . "\\dc1\netlogon\PSSubs\Logging_Functions.ps1"
} 
catch { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Error[0]) }

try {
    Log-Start -LogPath "\\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs" -LogName "Test_Log.log" -ScriptVersion "1.0"
} 
catch { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Error[0]) }
```

Where `Logging_Functions.ps` is from [here](http://9to5it.com/powershell-logging-v2-easily-create-log-files/), and I have posted the code for the first function I try to call (`Log-Start`) nelow.

```
Function Log-Start{
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Creates log file

  .DESCRIPTION
    Creates log file with path and name that is passed. Checks if log file exists, and if it does deletes it and creates a new one.
    Once created, writes initial logging data

  .PARAMETER LogPath
    Mandatory. Path of where log is to be created. Example: C:\Windows\Temp

  .PARAMETER LogName
    Mandatory. Name of log file to be created. Example: Test_Script.log

  .PARAMETER ScriptVersion
    Mandatory. Version of the running script which will be written in the log. Example: 1.5

  .INPUTS
    Parameters above

  .OUTPUTS
    Log file created

  .NOTES
    Version:        1.0
    Author:         Luca Sturlese
    Creation Date:  10/05/12
    Purpose/Change: Initial function development

    Version:        1.1
    Author:         Luca Sturlese
    Creation Date:  19/05/12
    Purpose/Change: Added debug mode support

  .EXAMPLE
    Log-Start -LogPath "C:\Windows\Temp" -LogName "Test_Script.log" -ScriptVersion "1.5"
  #>

  [CmdletBinding()]

  Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LogPath, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$LogName, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ScriptVersion)

  Process{
    $sFullPath = $LogPath + "\" + $LogName

    #Check if file exists and delete if it does
    If((Test-Path -Path $sFullPath)){
      Remove-Item -Path $sFullPath -Force
    }

    #Create file and start logging
    New-Item -Path $sFullPath -ItemType File

    # This version displays an annoying erro
    # New-Item -Path $LogPath -Value $LogName -ItemType File

    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "***************************************************************************************************"
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "Started processing at [$([DateTime]::Now)]."
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "***************************************************************************************************"
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value ""
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "Running script version [$ScriptVersion]."
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value ""
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value "***************************************************************************************************"
    Add-Content -Path $sFullPath -Value ""

    #Write to screen for debug mode
    Write-Debug "***************************************************************************************************"
    Write-Debug "Started processing at [$([DateTime]::Now)]."
    Write-Debug "***************************************************************************************************"
    Write-Debug ""
    Write-Debug "Running script version [$ScriptVersion]."
    Write-Debug ""
    Write-Debug "***************************************************************************************************"
    Write-Debug ""
  }
}
```

Comment: The only way would be to analyse keywords and determine the MINIMUM version the code requires to run.

Comment: Scripts aren't written *with* a version. They are written *for* a version. That is, they use features, syntax, etc. and that determines what versions of powershell they are compatible with. **How** is the script "not working" for them? Is it not running at all? Is it giving an error?

Comment: I think you mean "check which version of PowerShell can be used to _run_ a script". The script author should use the `#requires` directive to dictate a minimum required version of PowerShell needed to run a script; otherwise, the script may generate errors.

Comment: Thanks people - I can see that this is obviously not possible without analysing the code or being told by the writer which version was the target. @EtanReisner the issue is with .\Dot-Sourcing a PSLogging script and for some reason it simply doesn't work and I can't find out which version the script is written in. It doesn't work in that a `try{} catch{}` reveals that `Start-Log is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet ...` even though it exists in the dot-sourced file!

Comment: "Simply doesn't work" doesn't say much. There are **no** errors? What is the script supposed to do? Does **any** of it work? Does enabling debugging/tracing show anything?

Comment: @EtanReisner added some details, but there is not much more I can check, as this was for the purpose of creating a log file - the logging works perfectly when I run it on my PC but when executed as part of a network logon script it fails with the above message (edit on previous comment)

Comment: Show the script or at least the relevant pieces? Assuming you want help figuring out why that might be happening.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've posted some extra details - thanks for offering to help. I am still running this against my test user and no logfile is being created, but I am now also not seeing any errors ...

Comment: You aren't giving `Log-Start` any data to process that I can see. What should it be logging here?

Comment: `Log-Start` just creates the initial file and then you use `Log-Write` to add more lines to the file. I'm starting to think this will be a lot easier if I just write my own logging functions as these have already caused me a few issues and it really is a pretty simple requirement

Comment: if your function is not being recognized, you may have an issue with dot sourcing line. Is the path correct? Do users have access to the share? Is the execution policy properly set to allow execution of scripts from network shares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way for a script to specify which version it requires is to uses `#Requires`:

```
      #Requires -Version <N>[.<n>]
      #Requires –PSSnapin <PSSnapin-Name> [-Version <N>[.<n>]]
      #Requires -Modules { <Module-Name> | <Hashtable> } 
      #Requires –ShellId <ShellId>
      #Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

See `help about_requires` for more info.

So placing #Requires in your script will make sure it will only run if the minimum required version is installed.

To answer the question in the OP title: if the script was written using `#Requires`, simply search the script for the `#Requires` keyword and parse for the `-Version` argument. If `#Requires` wasn't used, then see the comments to the OP.